# Exclude table row data from database with php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

So, im building an admin panel and i'm with some trouble on the confirm dialog before deleting some data. I'm using a plugin for the confirm dialog, confirmOn plugin. This is what i have:

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>Name01</td>
    <td>01/11/2014</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="bt-delete"><a href='?p=content/det_process&prc=$prc&ex=".$lMov['cd']."'></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name02</td>
    <td>01/10/2014</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="bt-delete"><a href='?p=content/det_process&prc=$prc&ex=".$lMov['cd']."'></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name03</td>
    <td>01/09/2014</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td class="bt-delete"><a href='?p=content/det_process&prc=$prc&ex=".$lMov['cd']."'></a></td>
</tr>
[etc...]
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.bt-delete').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed) {
        if(confirmed) { // Clicked yes

        } else { // Clicked no

        }
    });                
});
```

The question is, i already have some php code before to connect with my DB and show the result on my table also the code to exclude the row. If i don't use the confirm plugin i can delete the row just fine, but i want to confirm it, so the client doesn't exclude something for acident.

Also, how can i select just one specific row even if all of them are using the same class?
I tried something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.bt-delete', function(event){
    alert("Button is working");
});
```

With a data-id="" in each of the buttons, but didn't worked as well.

What can i do to make it work?
How can i insert that php function with the jquery click event?

I know i could use ajax to call an external php file, but i don't want to do that, since i already have all the codes running in that same page.

Comment: You should use ajax to run the request if the confirm button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ajax to run the query after the button has been clicked. something like this.
you will need to edit the post line to make sure it goes to the right file with the right vars.

```
   <a data-cd='".$lMov['cd']."' class='bt-delete'>

$(function() {
    $('.bt-delete').confirmOn('click', function(e, confirmed) {
        if(confirmed) { // Clicked yes
            var cd = $(this).data("cd");
            $.post('?p=content/det_process&prc=$prc&ex='+cd, function() {
                alert("worked");
            });
        } else { // Clicked no

        }
    });                
});
```

I Have edited the code, i have put a data tag on the  and also given it the class.

Here is a link to the jquery examples.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: yeah, i'm almost there. Each button is showing the confirm box and if i click yes i have the alert confirming it's working. But the problem is to mix the php code with the jquery because of the " and ' quote mark. Do you know how to solve this? If i leave the 'cd' the jquery doesn't work at all and if i change to " the php doesn't work.

Comment: Its kind of working. Bu it's always deleting the first row, not the one i clicked on. Do you think it's something with php or can we fix it with jquery? Oh, and also it does delete the row, but only if i refresh the page. It's not in real time.

Comment: Well, i've made it. I needed to set the var cd = ''; outside the function, then i used i simple .click() to set the cd = '$this.data('id'); and in the .confirmOn() i just called the cd var. Just used a .reload so the page auto reload after the function and its everything ok now.